# JS - How to remove all whitespaces except in the middle of the string, that is generated using substr() function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, substr

I'm creating a JS / JQuery calculator and there is an `#info` element, which shows the user what they typed, or what is the calculation sequence like in the "Windows 10 Calculator", here:
[image]

I've tried many things which I'll list below but they didn't work.

---

Let me show you how it should look like:

1. The user just pressed the "Sqrt" button. The `#info` element has changed accordingly. By using "Inspect element", we can see, `#info` element has one whitespace from each side: `" √(0) "`.
   [image]
2. Let's press the button one more time and see what we've got. Now, the `#info` element has more whitespaces: `" √( √(0)  )"`. One from the left side, one after the first `√(`, and two whitespaces after the `√(0)`, until we reach `)`. This behavior is caused by `substr()` function.

   **However, it should be only one whitespace each side** `√(0)` string. Without any other whitespaces. `substr()` function **copies my whitespaces** and that's the wrong thing.

   So, above, using `" √( √(0)  )"` example, it should be `"√( √(0) )"`, and by pressing "Sqrt" button again, we should get the result of `#info` as `"√(√( √(0) ))"`.
   [image]

---

```js
let firstResult, firstResultWithSign;

$("#sqrt").on("click", function() {
  if (typeof firstResult === "undefined") {
    firstResult = $("#result h3").text();
  }

  if (typeof firstResultWithSign === 'undefined') {
    firstResultWithSign = ' \u221A(' + firstResult + ') ';
  }

  $("#result h3").text(Math.sqrt($("#result h3").text()));

  if (
    $("#info")
    .text()
    .lastIndexOf("\u221A") > -1
  ) {
    /**************************************************************************************/
    $('#info').text($('#info').text().substr(0, $('#info').text().lastIndexOf(firstResultWithSign) + 3) + firstResultWithSign + $('#info').text().substr($('#info').text().indexOf(')') + 1) + ')');
    /**************************************************************************************/
  } else {
    $("#info").html(firstResultWithSign);
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background-image: url("https://images8.alphacoders.com/702/702959.jpg");
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.text-center {
  text-align: center;
}

#result {
  background-color: #eee;
  min-height: 150px;
  max-height: 200px;
  position: relative;
}

#result h3 {
  font-size: 40px;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 15px;
  right: 15px;
  -webkit-user-select: text;
  user-select: text;
}

.history {
  text-align: right;
  padding: 17px 17px 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
}

.history:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

#main-panel {
  background-color: #eee;
}

#title {
  float: left;
  padding: 17px;
}

#info {
  position: absolute;
  right: 15px;
  top: 55px;
  color: #616161;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  width: calc(25% - 5px);
  background-color: #ddd;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 0 4px 4px 0;
  line-height: 40px;
}

#one,
#two,
#three,
#four,
#five,
#six,
#seven,
#eight,
#nine,
#zero {
  background-color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#divide:hover,
#times:hover,
#minus:hover,
#plus:hover,
#equals:hover {
  background-color: #01579b !important;
  color: #fff;
}

#divide:active,
#times:active,
#minus:active,
#plus:active,
#equals:active {
  background-color: #005395 !important;
  color: #fff;
}

.material-icons {
  font-size: 22px;
}

.column:first-child {
  margin-left: 4px;
}

.column:hover {
  background-color: #bcbcbc !important;
}

.column:active {
  background-color: #aeaeae !important;
}

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.fa-erase-left:before {
  content: "⌫";
}

.three-dots {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.overflow-x-auto {
  overflow-x: auto;
}

:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

footer {
  font-size: 0.85rem;
  margin: 1rem 0;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}

footer a:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0.0625rem;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
  transform: scaleX(0);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}

footer a:hover:before {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
  transform: scaleX(1);
}

.calculator-container {
  width: 45%;
  min-width: 200px;
  margin: 2.5rem auto 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<div class="calculator-container text-center">
  <div id="result">
    <div id="title">Calculator</div>
    <div class="history" title="History"><i class="material-icons">&#xE889;</i></div>
    <div id="info"></div>
    <h3 data-auto-generated="true" data-true-zero="true">0</h3>
  </div>
  <div id="main-panel">
    <div class="row">
      <div id="percentage" class="column">%</div>
      <div id="sqrt" class="column">&#x0221A;</div>
      <div id="exponentiation-by-two" class="column">x<sup>2</sup></div>
      <div id="one-divide-by-x" class="column"><sup>1</sup>/x</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div id="ce" class="column">CE</div>
      <div id="c" class="column">C</div>
      <div id="erase-left" class="column">
        <div class="fa-erase-left"></div>
      </div>
      <div id="divide" class="column">&divide;</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div id="seven" class="column">7</div>
      <div id="eight" class="column">8</div>
      <div id="nine" class="column">9</div>
      <div id="times" class="column">&#215;</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div id="four" class="column">4</div>
      <div id="five" class="column">5</div>
      <div id="six" class="column">6</div>
      <div id="minus" class="column">&#8722;</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div id="one" class="column">1</div>
      <div id="two" class="column">2</div>
      <div id="three" class="column">3</div>
      <div id="plus" class="column">&#43;</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div id="plus-minus" class="column">&#177;</div>
      <div id="zero" class="column">0</div>
      <div id="comma" class="column">,</div>
      <div id="equals" class="column">&#61;</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <footer>
    <a href="https://codepen.io/Kestis500">Created by LukasLSC</a>
  </footer>
</div>
```

JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xob6Luhh/.

---

What didn't work?

1. Using `replace()`, because then the `substr()` will copy absolutely no whitespace.
2. Using `indexOf(firstResultWithSign)`.
3. Using `' ' + firstResultWithSignNoSpace + ' '`, this will make `substr()` to copy whitespaces.

I've tried almost 10 ways, however, they are very similar to 1 - 3.

Any ideas? :) Thank you.

Comment: Best formated question ever. Thank you good sir

Comment: use `trim()` function https://api.jquery.com/jquery.trim/

Comment: Really appreciate your comment, I've tried to make it look good :)

Comment: Let me understand. You are getting  " √( √(0) )" and whant to get  " √(√(0))"?

Comment: @TemaniAfif I've tried it and it didn't work. Please, test it on JsFiddle and you will see. Maybe you can make it work, but not me :)

Comment: We enjoy this kind of questions. you are not just dropping code and waiting for someone to figure your code out and give you a solution.

Comment: @GerardoBLANCO From " √( √(0) )", I'd like to get "√( √(0) )". One whitespace from each side of `√(0)`.

Comment: @LukasNaujokaitis why you don't want to remove white-spaces in middle of the expression string?

Comment: It's my own preference, nothing else.

Comment: @LukasNaujokaitis Leading and trailing spaces of value of `firstResultWithSign = ' \u221A(' + firstResult + ') ';`  giving such result. Look updated one [https://jsfiddle.net/xob6Luhh/12/](https://jsfiddle.net/xob6Luhh/12/)

Comment: Thank you for your research, however, I already knew that. It still doesn't work as expected :/

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? `$('#info').text($('#info').text().replace(firstResultWithSign, firstResultWithSign.substr(1,2) + firstResultWithSign + ')'));`

Comment: @LukasNaujokaitis It means now your issue is something else.

Comment: @Tanmay It's related to `substr()` 100% and it happens because of the string copy and that default string has one whitespace on each side. Maybe this issue could be fixed if I remove all whitespaces and after `substr()` function, manually add it, because there is only one match of `√(0)`. I'm not sure, not tested :)

Comment: @trincot I think so. Wow, good job, thank you very much :) You can post the answer so I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it with this statement:

```
$('#info').text(
    $('#info').text().replace(firstResultWithSign, firstResultWithSign.substr(1,2) 
                                                 + firstResultWithSign + ')')
);
```

There are several other ways to get the same, depending on how dynamic you want it to be. For instance:

```
$('#info').text(
    $('#info').text().replace(firstResultWithSign, 
                              firstResultWithSign.replace(/\s*([^(]*).*/, '$1($&)'))
);
```

Comment: Is the second code is more dynamic? If so, then how?

Comment: If the operator would take more characters than just one (as `√` is only one character, but we can imagine using `sqrt` as notation instead), then `substr(1,2)` would need to become `substr(1,5)` (in the first solution). The second solution just grabs whatever comes before the opening parenthesis. So whatever the length of the operator string, it would still work.

Comment: Can you explain what this does `($&)` in the second code `replace()` function? Using https://regexr.com/ didn't get any information, so I guess it's related specifically to JS?

Comment: Yes, it is specific to JS. In other languages it would be `$0` or `\0`: it represents the whole input string (so the value of `firstResultWithSign` in this case, as it will match completely).

Comment: Ok, but why do we need `(` and `)` around `$&`?

Comment: Because we need to add a pair of parentheses in the result that are not in the input. They are to be taken literal. The opening one could have been grabbed as part of the capture group (`$1`): in that case the extra opening parenthesis would not need to be included: `/\s*([^(]*.).*/, '$1$&)'`. Note the additional final dot in the capture group now.